# Difference of Hide from FormClosing event

Tags: c#, winforms

Can you even consider the `this.hide()` method as `FormClosing` event?  What I want to happen is when I close the form with the `x` button I want a different event to happen from opening another form and closing the current form.

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you're asking about. Please make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

The event triggered by Hide() is the VisibleChanged event of the form. In the event handler, you must then test the Visible property to identify if its Hide or Show.

Comment: Hah just searched for it. Yep, VisibleChanged will do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I have undertand you correct, the solution is as simple as raise the second event in the method that handle the first event.

Answer (score 0):

`FormClosing` / `FormClosed` isnt binded to `this.Hide()` as `Hide != Close`.

So yeah, you can fire different events for differents actions.
Therefore clicking `X` is binded to `FormClosing` / `FormClosed`.